# How would I add a message that states that "The answer is incorrect" into my php code

Tags: php, html

I would like to add a message that displays to the user that the answer they entered was incorrect AFTER they have already taken and submitted the quiz. I tried adding an if/else statement but get errors so I removed it. Any help would be appreciated. (also I know that using print: is annoying but its how I was showed how to program with PHP.)

```
<?php
require_once("includes.php");
require_once("classes/SiteTemplate.php");

if(isset($_SESSION['isLoggedIn'])) {
  $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = false;
  unset($_SESSION['isLoggedIn']);
}

$page = new SiteTemplate("Form Page");
$page->addHeadElement('<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/login.css">');
$page->finalizeTopSection();
$page->finalizeBottomSection();

print $page->getTopSection();
print "<form class=\"form-signin\" action=\"login_action.php\" method=\"POST\" class=\"form- 
signin\">";
if (isset($_SESSION['errors']) && count($_SESSION['errors']) > 0) {
  foreach ($_SESSION['errors'] as $errorIndex => $errorMessage) {
    print $errorMessage . "<br>\n";
  }
  unset($_SESSION['errors']);
}
print "<ul>\n";
print "  <li><a class=\"active\" href=\"home.php\">Home</a></li>\n";
print "  <li><a href=\"quiz.php\">Quiz</a></li>\n";
print "  <li><a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a></li>\n";
print "</ul>";

print "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
print "<html lang=\"en\">\n";
print "\n";
print "<head>\n";
print " \n";
print " <title>Quiz Results</title>\n";
print " \n";
print " <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />\n";
print "</head>\n";
print "\n";
print "<body>\n";
print "\n";
print " <div id=\"page-wrap\">\n";
print "\n";
print "     <h1>Results:</h1>\n";

        $answer1 = $_POST['question-1-answers'];
        $answer2 = $_POST['question-2-answers'];
        $answer3 = $_POST['question-3-answers'];
        $answer4 = $_POST['question-4-answers'];
    
        $totalCorrect = 0;
        
        if ($answer1 == "C") { $totalCorrect++; }
        if ($answer2 == "D") { $totalCorrect++; }
        if ($answer3 == "A") { $totalCorrect++; }
        if ($answer4 == "blue"||$answer4 == "Blue") { $totalCorrect++; }
        
        echo "<div id='results'>$totalCorrect / 4 correct</div>";




print "     \n";
print "    \n";
print " \n";
print " </div>\n";
print "\n";
print "</body>\n";
print "\n";
print "</html>";


        

print $page->getBottomSection();
```

Comment: What errors did you get, and where did you add this if/else?

Comment: I added the if/else to all of the if statements, and the error I get is Notice: Undefined index: question-1-answers in /home/jmask072/public_html/FinalSprint/result.php on line 45

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like homework help so I would suggest working through the logic of your question.  You have some code that determines if 4 questions were answered correctly and gives you a score out of 4.  You know which questions were answered correctly (if answer1 == C for ex).  Should be pretty straightforward to figure out how to use an else to print a message if an answer is wrong.

Comment: Please look into [here and now doc strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) as you printing every line is not good practice ;)

Comment: did you know you can break in and out of php? `?> html here <?php`

Comment: Seems your error is here on this line. `$answer1 = $_POST['question-1-answers'];` You need to check if your POST params has any input with that key. You can use isset function to check for this instead of just assigning it to a variable.